# How to get Dropdownlist selected value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, html.dropdownlistfor

How to get dropdownList selected Item from CSHTML page.

```
<div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("ROUTE_GROUP_ID", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ROUTE_GROUP_ID)
        </div>
```

Comment: Get value where? Server, Client?

Comment: If you use the `Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.selectedvalue, ...)` you probably wouldn't need to ask this question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want its value in jquery you can do like this

```
$('#ROUTE_GROUP_ID').val();
```

or if you want its value in controller you can access it from

```
Request.Form["ROUTE_GROUP_ID"]
```

or if your controller have a formcollection object then access the value like

```
formcollectionobj["ROUTE_GROUP_ID"]
```

Answer (score 0):

From your example, i don't see how you would get any selected value, since you haven't defined the SelectList from which your DropDownList will get it's values.

I'd suggest you to create a ViewModel, fill a SelectItemList with your RouteGroup, passing it's ID as value. Like this:

```
public class RouteGroupViewModel
{

  public string SelectedRouteGroup { get; set; }

  public List<SelectListItem> RouteGroup { get; set; }

  public void FillRouteGroup()
  {
    //Fill your SelectList with your RouteGroup values
  }

}
```

**On your view:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(item => item.SelectedRouteGroup, new SelectList(Model.RouteGroup, "Value", "Text"))
```

**And on your Controller:**

```
    public ActionResult RouteGroup(RouteGroupViewModel rgVM)
    {
        //To Do your controller operations
    }
```

With that you can get the DropDownList selected value.

Comment: i'm passing the list from viewbag i.e viewbag.ROUTE_GROUP_ID= db.RouteGroup.ToList();