# Setting field using Dropdownlist to select values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, razor

I am using asp.net mvc 4 web app c#. I have the following model:

```
 public class Job
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
    public JobType jobType { get; set; }


    //public int JobTypeId { get { return this.jobType.id; } }
}
```

Now I want to write a create action where the jobType attribute is set through a DropDownList. The create action:

```
//
    // GET: /Job/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        IEnumerable<JobType> jobtypes = db.JobTypes.ToList();
        ViewData.Add("jobTypeList", new SelectList(jobtypes , "id", "name"));
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Job/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Job job)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Jobs.Add(job);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(job);
    }
```

View:

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.jobType)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("jobTypeList")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.jobType)
    </div>
```

The DropDownList is working fine listing existing jobtypes. However, when a job is created the jobetype of the job is not set (the jobtype id is not set in the job row of the created job). As I am new to asp.net mvc, I am not sure what the form passes to the post create action: Does it pass the jobtype object or the jobtype id? Why does it not set the jobtype id for the created job? Do I have to set the jobtype id my self in post create action? If so how do I get the selected value of the DropDownList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

So to get the id of the selected value in the drop-down list, I just have a line like this:

```
int contentId= APIFactory.getContentAPI().getID(department.SelectedValue);
```

where the function getId() takes a name (the value in the drop-down) and then does a database query for the id of the department selected. Here is my getID() function

```
public int getID(String deptName)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> where = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    where.Add(DEPTNAME, deptName);
    DataTable dt = db.Query(ID, TABLE, where);
    return (int)dt.Rows[0][ID];
}
```

Note: You don't need the whole APIFactory thing for this, you could just throw the query in instead of the line I have, and it would work just as well. However, if you are using the same queries a lot, I would recommend it.

EDIT:
Since you are using a cshtml page and not a aspx page, use the method described here to get the value, and then my method to get the id:
[How to get Dropdownlist selected value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513149/how-to-get-dropdownlist-selected-value)

Comment: (I hope I understood you correctly)But I do not need the next id but the id of the jobtype which is selected by the dropdownlist. So the JobType exists already. The problem is, it is not set by the view form/[post]create action.

Comment: That is my problem, how do I get the value selected in the dropdown?

Comment: drop-down-name.SelectedValue should give you what's selected.
It will give you a string, and then use what I posted in my answer to get the id

Comment: OK, the name of the dropdownlost is "jobTypeList" as seen in the code above: so jobTypeList.SelectedValue should be work in the [post] create action , right? which it doesnt... It seems I still dont get the html helper dropdownlist(string name).

Comment: Ok so I assumed you have the dropdown in an .aspx file, and are calling jobTypeList.SelectedValue from the corresponding .aspx.cs file. If that is not the case, is your dropdown in a pure html file?
(if it is in a .aspx file, is it declared like this: 
    <asp:DropDownList ID="id" runat="server" />

Comment: My mistake, I assumed we were talking about a .cshtml view. So it is not a n .asp.cs file but a .cshtml.

Comment: ok I edited my answer again, hope it helps.
edit is at the bottom

Comment: OK, it worked. However I dont think it is a clean way to do it. Shouldnt it be possible to pass a list of JobType objects as values of the dropdownlist, so the post-form passes the correct selectedValue to the job instanc to be created? or are teh values of a dropdownlist restricted to primitive types? STILL: thank you very much for your help, I appriciat it.

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1732410.aspx/1
Try this if you're looking for something a little cleaner

Answer (score 0):

The way you have the view set up right now, only the Id of the selected job type will be posted.

You can update the Create method to only take in `int jobTypeList` and then create a add a Job based on the provided value.

Comment: Sorry,I have troubles to follow you: Do you mean the [post] create action should receive a int jobTypeList parameter?

Comment: But isn't that correct, that the ID of the jobtype is posted? As the JobType column in the job database is jobtype_id[int] (was created that way by the asp.net mvc framework).

Comment: Do I need to pass a selectlist containing JobType objects to the dropdownlist? If so how do I realize that?